# how to upload the IAP base64 receipt to the server?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I used JSONEncoder to get the data and used the following code to upload the receipt to the server.

```
// send to server
let url = URL(string: "https://ios.jobyme88.com/KidsLearnHindi/save-shopping.php")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = jsonData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    // check error
    if let error = error {
        print ("[shark-IAP] error: \(error)")
        return
    }

    // check response
    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
    (200...299).contains(response.statusCode) else {
        print ("[shark-IAP] server error")
        return
    }


    // print data from server
    guard let data = data else {
        print("[shark-IAP] no data")
        return
   }
    
    let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        print ("[shark-IAP] got data: \(String(describing: dataString))")
}
task.resume()
```

But I found the string is too long that the server just receive empty string.
Do you know how to upload the receipt?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this myself some time ago and worked out the following solution for sending a receipt and receiving the validation result:

Base method to create and handle the HTTP request

```swift
    func sendPost(url: URL, receiptBase64String: String) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.timeoutInterval = 15

        let boundary = "Boundary-\(UUID().uuidString)"
        request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let postParameters = ["receipt": receiptBase64String]
        request.httpBody = self.createBodyWithParameters(boundary: boundary, parameters: postParameters)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            // TODO: Handle Server response
        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Helper method to create the request body as data

```swift
    public func createBodyWithParameters(boundary: String, parameters: [String: String]?) -> Data {
        let body = NSMutableData()

        if let parameters = parameters {
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                body.append(string: "--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.append(string: "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
                body.append(string: "\(value)\r\n")
            }
        }

        body.append(string: "--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body as Data
    }
```

Extension to allow appending to `NSMutableData`

```swift
private extension NSMutableData {
    func append(string: String) {
        if let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true) {
            append(data)
        }
    }
}
```

*Credits to http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/image-upload-example/*

Comment: thank for your detailed answer, will try this!